# ArgumentError Received wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

This is pretty scary, but I've spent about a week developing an app and have just been hit with the following error when running the 'Rails S' command. My app doesn't seem to want to start up anymore.

I'm sure with the help of the wonderful Stackoverflow community we can solve this one!

Edit: Thought I would include my GitHub for good measure - https://github.com/Apane/Startupblog

## ArgumentError

```
      Received wrong number of arguments. [#<Logger:0x007fe8d56bb280 
    @progname="omniauth", @level=0, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007fe8d56bb230
     @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x007fe8d56bb140  
     @datetime_format=nil>, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x007fe8d56bb1e0 @shift_size=nil, 
    @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mutex=#
    <Logger::LogDevice::LogDeviceMutex:0x007fe8d56bb1b8 @mon_owner=nil,  
    @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=# <Mutex:0x007fe8d56bb168>>>>]
```

### Full Trace:

```
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:136:in `initialize'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:82:in `new'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:82:in `block in use'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:130:in `[]'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:130:in `block in to_app'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:130:in `each'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:130:in `inject'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/builder.rb:130:in `to_app'
omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1918359078568265758__call__4170314405657891017__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What did you change between when it was working and when it wasn't? Are you using any sort of version control?

Comment: Thanks for your response Beerlington. That is the strange thing, I changed absolutely nothing! sidenote: i've added my github page to the initial post if that helps any!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is actually a syntax error and looks like it was introduced when you added omniauth to the project. On [line 3 of your omniauth initializer](https://github.com/Apane/Startupblog/blob/master/config/initializers/omniauth.rb#L3) there's a trailing comma. Get rid of that and you should be fine.